# ViewModel returns empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return Viewmodel values but i can't get them in the view

Here is my code

```
public ActionResult Please(string id)
{
    UserViewModel mo = new UserViewModel();
    mo.WriterName = "aaa";
    return View(mo);
}
```

Comment: post your view code also.

Comment: What error (if any) are you getting ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Try this on your View

```
@model [Namespace].UserViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.WriterName</h2>
```

Comment: What are you attempting to solve when you don't actually know the issue?

Comment: @JamieR Lucy wrote: 'but i can't get them in the view'. I show how to get this value in the view.